# How does pandas return 'data' attribute of DataFrame object upon creation of the object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, open-source

I was going through and trying to understand the implementation of the Pandas Data Frame here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L236

A data frame can be created as:

```
dictionary = {'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2':['a', 'b', 'c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

`df` is an object of the class `DataFrame`.
The `data` attribute of the object holds the actual dictionary that is being used to create the data frame.

```
print(df)
>  col1 col2
 0   1   a
 1   2   b
 2   3   c
```

When we do `print(df)`, the data of the object is printed, instead of just the object of class `DataFrame` (like `<__main__.DataFrame object at 0x112edd070>`).
Hence, we can access and print the `data` in the `DataFrame` object when we do `print(df)` instead of explicitly needing to call the attribute `data` of the object as `print(df.data)`. How is the `data` attribute of the `DataFrame` object returned upon creation of the object `df` of the Data Frame?

Where is the gap in my understanding of the the object of the class is created and attributes returned?

Comment: I would imagine that methods and properties have been written to access/use that underlying data. It isn't clear what you are asking , at least to me.

Comment: `data` is just an input parameter and can be one of several types. Its data is extracted into a pandas data structure and no reference to the original `data` object is kept. So, you can't get the original data dict you used back from the dataframe itself.

Comment: `df.data` doesn't return anything, do you mean `df._data`? Incidentally, here you can see that the underlying data is not the original dictionary.